# What are the characteristics of a transformation matrix?

Tags: soft-question

You have been given a transformation matrix 
$\begin{bmatrix} a &b \\
c & d\end{bmatrix}$ to transform shape $X$ into $Y$

What are the different characteristics of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$?

At the moment, I know what the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a\\c \end{bmatrix}$and $\begin{bmatrix}b\\d \end{bmatrix} $ each will show the resulting shape in relation to the identity matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1 \end{bmatrix}$

But if $a$ is to be incremented, what will be the result of the final shape $Y$ in general, such as shewness and other factors such as stretch in x axis?

Comment: The resulting shape of *what*?

Comment: @Travis, please review edit